# if statement in main function c++

Tags: c++, xcode, if-statement

Okay, probably a dumb question to you guys but I can't figure it out.

So I'm taking a c++ basics course in class and so far I'm struggling/crying.

I can't show you guys my code because I'm not allowed/there are consequences if I'm caught but I could probably give a example.

I'm using xcode. So when I compile, I get two errors below (image provided).
I searched for similar questions, but those seem too complex compared to what I'm doing. In addition, the only includes I have are iostream and string.

I know the problem occurs when I add an if statement in my main function. I know this because when I delete it, everything compiles as expected. Yet when I add it again to the main function, these errors occur.

So my question is, based on what I know, is it proper to add an if statements whenever in the main function?

Below is an example. I wrote the functions below and called above.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// example functions that I just made up to explain the structure of my actual code. 

//Don't bother trying to understand it. It's just to explain that 
//I wrote my functions at the 
// bottom and called it at the top.

int  getNumberofWins(param1, param2);

string getTheName(int player1);

int executeCycle(string p1_name, string p2_name);

 void stateWinner(string winner_name);


 int main {

 playerOne = getTheName(1);
 playerTwo = getTheName(2);


 r1 = executeCycle(playerOne, playerTwo);



 r2= executeCycle(playerOne, playerTwo);

 totalWin1 = getNumberOfWins(1, r1, r2);
 totalWin2 = getNumberOfWins(2, r1, r2);

 cout << totalWin1;

 //This is the where I get the errors. When I delete the if statement, 
 //Everything compiles. When I add it, an error occurs.

 if (totalWin1 == 2){
    stateWinner(playerOne);
 } 
 return 0;
}

string getTheName(int player1){

string playerOne;
string playerTwo;

if(player_number == 1){ code code code
}

 }

int getNumberofWins (int param1, int param2){
code code code
}

int executeCycle(string p1_name, string p2_name){
  code code code
}

void stateWinner(string winner_name){
if(!winner_name.empty()){
    code code code
 }
```

I hope it's fine if the code above isn't accurate. I think the point is that once I add my if statement to the main function, the two errors show up.

[image]

[image]

actually...now that I look at it, they both seem like similar errors. I just don't know why they both appear...

Sorry if this is an obvious answer or if it isn't clear.

Comment: How is `win` defined and where?

Comment: There's no `stateWinner` function declaration.

Comment: The error message says `announceWinner` -- I don't see any mention of that in your code, so it's not clear why that's happening. It would make more sense if the error complained about `stateWinner`.

Comment: Above is just a made up example to show the structure of my actual code. I was assuming that syntax or forgetting to declare a function wouldn't matter because I know my function works if I take out the *if statement* but it doesn't if I add the if statement back in. Unless the errors occur because of syntax errors.

Comment: I'll actually edit my code example above to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

The "announceWinner" function is not defined anywhere, ie there's no

```
void announceWinner () {
    // code
}
```

anywhere.  Either you haven't written it yet, or the file that contains it is not being compiled & linked with the main program.